# How to store part of a command into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have the follwing bash script

```
CMD="\( -path ./.git -o -name .gitignore \) -prune -o";

find . $CMD -print
find . $CMD -exec chmod 440 {} \+
```

I need to list all files except the ones in .git dir and .gitignore files and than chmod them.

Comment: `find` has a `-not` option.

Comment: To expand on what @tripleee said you don't use a string you use an array. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @MarcB GNU find does, POSIX and busybox does not (they use `!`).

Comment: @MarcB `-not -path` is not the correct way to `-prune` something.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the [reasons not to put code in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), you really should not be running `find` twice, especially when you can combine `-print` and `-exec` in one command.

Answer (score 2):

tripleee's concerns notwithstanding, the correct way to code that is with an array:

```
find_opts=( \( -path ./.git -o -name .gitignore \) -prune -o )

find . "${find_opts[@]}" -print
find . "${find_opts[@]}" -exec chmod 440 {} \+
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `find`, you could use `dotglob` and `extglob`:

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob
for file in !(.git?(ignore)); do echo "$file" && chmod 440 "$file"; done
```

`dotglob` means that glob expansion also includes files beginning with a `.` and `extglob` enables "extended globbing", which allows you to negate matches, among other things. In this example, the glob matches all files that are not `.git` or `.gitignore`.

To unset these options after you are done, you can use `shopt -u dotglob extglob`.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob for more details.